# How to know which pages a single user visited on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I defined some custom variables to make it possible to identify when a specific user visits my website. So for each user I can see when and how many pages they visited, avg visit duration etc.

Is it possible to know which pages they have visited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by going to Content > Site Content > All Pages and adding a custom segment (in Advanced Segments) that allowed me to filter by custom variable (ie, user id in my case). This way it shows all pages viewed by the user I've filtered